# what alternative of resizableimagewithcapinsets Ios method in C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How do I stretch images in C# like the IOS method
`resizableimagewithcapinsets`
 does?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to resize image right? please check this code below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Class contaning method to resize an image and save in JPEG format
/// </summary>
public class ImageHandler
{ 

public void Save(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, int quality, string filePath)
{
    // Get the image's original width and height
    int originalWidth = image.Width;
    int originalHeight = image.Height;

    // To preserve the aspect ratio
    float ratioX = (float)maxWidth / (float)originalWidth;
    float ratioY = (float)maxHeight / (float)originalHeight;
    float ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    // New width and height based on aspect ratio
    int newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);
    int newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);

    // Convert other formats (including CMYK) to RGB.
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    // Draws the image in the specified size with quality mode set to HighQuality
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the JPEG codec.
    ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = this.GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // Create an Encoder object for the Quality parameter.
    Encoder encoder = Encoder.Quality;

    // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
    EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    // Save the image as a JPEG file with quality level.
    EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(encoder, quality);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;
    newImage.Save(filePath, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);
}

/// <summary>
/// Method to get encoder infor for given image format.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="format">Image format</param>
/// <returns>image codec info.</returns>
  private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat format)
  {
      return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().SingleOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == format.Guid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Minh Bui for replay  ..but its not about image resizing..my quetion was about image stretching as in IOS.